# nftables or fw4 issue with timebased traffic rules

Tags: firewall, openwrt, date-time, nftables

Since the OpenWRT ver > 22.3  does use NFTABLES instead of IPTABLES
I got issue with some firewall (fw4) time based traffic rules that I
have no idea how to solve them.

The firewall rule is as follows

```
config rule
   option name 'Block-Traffic'
   option src 'lan'
   option dest 'wan'
   option target 'DROP'
   option utc_time '1'
   list proto 'all'
   option start_date '2022-10-01'
   option stop_date '2022-10-02'
   option start_time '11:50:00'
   option stop_time '12:15:00'
   option enabled '1'
```

The problem is with the start_date and stop_date format,
I have tried many date formats but I always get following
error when I execute /etc/init.d/firewall reload command.

*(Block-Traffic) option 'start_date' specifies invalid value '2022-10-02'*

*/dev/stdin:102:31-51: Error: Cannot parse date
meta nfproto ipv4 meta time "2022-10-01 00:00:00"-"2022-10-02 00:00:00" meta hour "11:50:00"-"12:15:00" counter jump drop_to_wan comment "!fw4: Block-Traffic"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^*

I am tired of trying differnt date formats, I would like to know if there is a bug with the fw4 or ipset or not.
I have to overcome this annoying issue and any help is appreciated.

For your reference I am using OpenWRT snapshot mine is snapshot Powered by LuCI Master (git-22.208.55978-37422e8) with ipset installed

Comment: I can just tell that on my system (Linux 5.19 nftables 1.0.5, not OpenWRT) I can't reproduce this error. After doing this: `nft add table inet t; nft add chain inet t c; nft add chain inet t drop_to_wan` , the rule displayed in error by OP works as is if single quoted: `nft add rule inet t c 'meta nfproto ipv4 meta time "2022-10-01 00:00:00"-"2022-10-02 00:00:00" meta hour "11:50:00"-"12:15:00" counter jump drop_to_wan comment "!fw4: Block-Traffic"'`.

Comment: (also accepted with nftables 0.9.8)